# How to check life status of functions in android studio java

Tags: java, android

In Android Studio java file, under OnCreate method I'm calling some functions but not able to know that whether all functions were processed successfully or not.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

    refreshData1 ();
    refreshData2 ();
    refreshData3 ();
}

private void refreshData1 () {
   some code

}

private void refreshData2 () {
   some code

}

private void refreshData3 () {
   some code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to do some reading about boolean methods, [here](http://www.vias.org/javacourse/chap05_07.html) you have a quick tutorial.

Make your methods to return a result based on whatever logic you need. If your methods are not dependent between them and can be executed sequentially one after the other regardless if any fails, then you could write it as next:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

    final boolean result1 = refreshData1();
    final boolean result2 = refreshData2();
    final boolean result3 = refreshData3();

    if (!result1 || !result2 || !result3) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Something failed");
    }
}

private boolean refreshData1() {

   // If whatever logic fails, then return false

    return true;
}

........
........
```